# A lot of MySqlExceptions in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql

A mysterious error occures a huge amount of `MySqlException` in `MySql.Data.dll`

Sample code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
try
{
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = conn.createCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText="SP_StoredProcedure1";
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@piID",1);
        cmd.Parameters["@piID"].Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
        using(MySqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader())
            while(reader.Read())
                Console.Log(reader["piID"]);
    }
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{
    Console.Log(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if(conn.State==ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```

And I keep getting the following errors:

> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException' in MySql.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help others in the future. It is unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Does console.log handle nulls gracefully? Maybe `reader["piID"]` is null. And you might want to log `ex.ToString()` instead of just the `Message`.